# Animated fanplot

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I am using the following code to try to generate an animated fanplot in matlab. 
It seems to work fine, however, it does open a new window for each iteration. I took the command 'ax.NextPlot = 'replaceChildren';' from an example but it does not work with fanplot...

Any suggestions on how to have the animation in one single window?

Many thanks

```
m = 0.06;
v = 0.18;
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));

X = lognrnd(mu,sigma,10,10000)';
historical= [1 0.06];
f=[2  X(:,1)'];
forecast =  vertcat(f, [3  X(:,2)']);
fanplot(historical,forecast);
axis tight manual
ax = gca;
ax.NextPlot = 'replaceChildren';
loops = 10;
F(loops) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
for j = 4 :loops

    forecast = conc(forecast, j, X);
    fanplot(historical,forecast);

    drawnow
    F(j) = getframe;
end
function y = conc(f,x,X)

y = vertcat(f, [x  X(:,x-1)']);
end
```

Comment: Please always try to construct a [mcve], i.e. specify `mu` and `sigma`.